# Docker failed to initialize Docker Desktop is shutting down windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I tried re-install and start again. but same issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCU4X.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users\Urpcname\AppData\Roaming\Docker delete Docker folder's  inside files and restart the docker. After we can see, its working fine. (this is for the Windows OS right)